# How to modify tick's range in Image3D

Tags: image3d

Suppose we have an array of color data

```
colorArray = ParallelTable[With[{v = RandomReal[]},
Append[List @@ ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][v], If[v >= .8, .5, 0]]
], {z, 0, .1, .005}, {y, 0, 1, .1}, {x, 0, 10, 2}];
```

And we use `Image3D` to visualize them

```
is = 350;
Image3D[
colorArray, "Real", ColorSpace -> "RGB",
ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2}, SphericalRegion -> True,
Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
ImageSize -> is, ImageResolution -> 3*is]
```

[image]

The problem is that the ticks are the relative position of each `RGBColor` element in the array, not the actual range of `x`, `y`, and `z` (`{z, 0, .1, .005}, {y, 0, 1, .1}, {x, 0, 10, 2}`). My question is how can we change the ticks to show the actual range of `x`, `y`, and `z`? A direct implement seems impossible because in `colorArray` no data about the original `x`, `y`, and `z` values are stored (actually we cannot store them in `colorArray` due to the requirement of `Image3D`).

Comment: Have you seen `Raster3D`? This allows you to specify the range of x, y and z.

Comment: @Simon Woods, Yes I know it, but the `Image3D` has better plot quality for medium sized bins, so I wish there could be a solution for `Image3D`. I have tried to extract a bare frame and use `Show` to combine it and the 3D image, but that did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit** Thanks to [matheorem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4742/matheorem) for simplifying this a good deal.

[`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html) is relatively new and doesn't have all the options that other `Graphics3D` objects have, but we can work with it because it can be used with `Show` like any other 3D graphics object.  The strategy here is to only give those options to `Image3D` which are unique to it, while giving all other options to `Show`.

`Image3D` produces a plot where the data ranges for the three dimensions are equal to the dimensions of the input array, similar to the 2D functions `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot`.  However, unlike those functions we can't supply the option `DataRange` to `Image3D`.  So we need to manually specify a scaling function for the tickmarks.  That is, when you give the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) manually, you can specify the position and the label for each tick mark, i.e. in a list like $\{\{x_1, label_1\},\{x_2, label_2\},...\}$.  This is tedious to do by hand, so we can do it functionally.

There are two ways I can think of to do this.  The first is by using the `CustomTicks` package and the second is by sending a function to `Ticks`.

I like to use the `CustomTicks` package, available here:  http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/  It makes it really easy to rescale the tickmark values.  Just download the CustomTicks.m file and place it somewhere in your `$Path`.

And this isn't really clear from this example, because the data is random, but in order for the plot ranges to match up it is necessary to reverse the first two levels of the 3D array.

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"]

colorArray = 
  ParallelTable[
   With[{v = RandomReal[]}, 
    Append[List @@ ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][v], 
     If[v >= .8, .5, 0]]], {z, 0, .1, .005}, {y, 0, 1, .1}, {x, 0, 10,
     2}];
{xmax, ymax, zmax} = {10, 1, .1};
{zdim, ydim, xdim} = Dimensions[colorArray][[;; 3]];


Show[Image3D[Reverse[colorArray,{1,2}], "Real", ColorSpace -> "RGB"],
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2},
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Boxed -> True,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
 ImageSize -> 350,
 ImageResolution -> 750,
 Ticks -> {
   LinTicks[0, 10, TickPostTransformation -> (# xdim/xmax &)], 
   LinTicks[0, 1, TickPostTransformation -> (# ydim/ymax &)], 
   LinTicks[0, .1, TickPostTransformation -> (# zdim/zmax &)]}]
```

[image]

A somewhat less elegant solution that doesn't rely on an external package is

```
Show[Image3D[Reverse[colorArray,{1,2}], "Real", ColorSpace -> "RGB"],
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2},
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 Boxed -> True,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
 ImageSize -> 350,
 ImageResolution -> 750,
 Ticks -> {
   Function[{min, max}, {# xdim/xmax, NumberForm[N@#, {3, 2}] } & /@ 
     FindDivisions[Round[{min, max}] xmax/xdim, 5]], 
   Function[{min, max}, {# ydim/ymax, NumberForm[N@#, {3, 2}] } & /@ 
     FindDivisions[Round[{min, max}] ymax/ydim, 5]], 
   Function[{min, max}, {# zdim/zmax, NumberForm[N@#, {3, 2}] } & /@ 
     FindDivisions[Round[{min, max}] zmax/zdim, 5]]
   }]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you!

Comment: Hi, Jason B. What do you mean by " edit the tickmarks manually "? I didn't find a way for manually editing

Comment: @matheorem I meant *enter* the tickmarks for the contouplot3D manually, sorry.  You can enter a list for the tickmarks that would let you specify the positions, lengths, and label for each tickmark.  But it's easier to specify a scaling function like above.

Comment: @JasonB Yeah, this package is really handy. Thanks : )

Comment: @JasonB Hi, Jason B. I found you actually don't need to create an empty Frame. Just embedded the `Image3D` in `Show` and apply the Ticks options in `Show` is a direct way.

Comment: @matheorem - that's great!  I can update this answer or you can put in another answer

Comment: @JasonB An update is enough, it is a small improvement  : )

Comment: @JasonB Why now your image is much clear than OP's? I can not reproduce your image. What have you done?

Comment: @JasonB And also I just realize there is one more problem in coordinate. Check out tutorial/ImageProcessing, in the coordinate section. The coordinate should be upside down, because `Image3D` stack from top to bottom.

Comment: I don't know why mine is more clear, I get pretty much the same image from OP that I would get from my code  http://i.imgur.com/sFC6uxo.png .  Will look at the coordinate issue

Comment: I think we should `Reverse[colorArray,{1,2,3}]` before `Image3D`, to make the coordinate back to normal

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean by "I don't know why mine is more clear, I get pretty much the same image from OP that I would get from my code"

Comment: You said "Why now your image is much clear than OP's", and I pointed out in the attached image that the image I get from OP's code and from my own are identical aside from the tick marks

Comment: And interestingly enough, you have to reverse the first two levels of the array, but not the third.

Comment: Are you sure not a total reverse? My test shows that total reverse is the right to go. And I remember before your updating, your image3D is the same as OP, but now your image3D is clearer, this is weird, because I can't get such a clear image3D as yours

Comment: Here's the test I did on reversing:  Make an array with just a single nonzero value, and you should know exactly the coordinates for it.  http://pastebin.com/raw/07tWR6CH  - run the code here and you should get these results:  http://i.imgur.com/QdIZ7m0.png

Comment: Er...Jason B. Don't forget to add @ sign, because I don't want to miss your commnet : )

Comment: @JasonB Oh, my fault. I made a wrong test. You are right on reverse.  Thank you for correcting me. About the image quality, I think your mma is quite different to mine now, see http://postimg.org/image/oxzgzxeu1/ . The image is not the same as yours. Did you update your mma or using a different setting or new computer maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35451/discussion-between-jason-b-and-matheorem).