# Convert data from Image3D to ListPlot3D

Tags: image-processing, image3d

Let's suppose I have created a 3d image of gray scale Images with:

```
image3d = Image3D[Table[readImage[i], {i, numberOfImages}]];
```

and

```
image3dSlices = Image3DSlices[image3d]
```

To show the 3d image I can use:

```
image3d
```

or

```
Image3D[image3dSlices[[startImageNumber;;endImageNumber]]]
```

Is it somehow possible to convert the image data so that I could use `ListPlot3D` or `ListDensityPlot3D`? Please see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157419/image3d-plot-physical-axes-scales):

Comment: `ListDensityPlot[ImageData@image3dSlices[[imageNumber]]]` and `ListPlot3D[ImageData@image3dSlices[[imageNumber]]]`?

Comment: @kglr: Thank you. But how could I use e.g. `ListPlot3D` for all the images at once?

Comment: `ListPlot3D[ImageData/@image3dSlices]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your linked example looks to be essentially binary. Maybe something like this is what you are after?

```
img = Image3D[
  Table[ SparseArray[
     Rule[#, 1] & /@ 
      Round@CirclePoints[{10, 10}, (81 - (i - 10)^2)/20, 100] ,
      {20,20}] // Normal, {i, 19}]]
```

[image]

```
 ListPointPlot3D[Position[ImageData[img], 1., {3}]]
```

[image]

If your data isnt exactly binary maybe some threshold will work eg.

```
ListPointPlot3D[Position[ImageData[img], x_Real /; x > .1, {3}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
slices = Image3DSlices[ExampleData@{"TestImage3D", "CTengine"}];
Row[{Show[slices[[14]], ImageSize -> 300], 
  ListDensityPlot[ImageData@slices[[14]], ImageSize -> 300],
  ListPlot3D[ImageData@slices[[14]], ImageSize -> 300]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is very helpful to plot the single image slices and be able to control the axes ranges (ticks). Great.